# How to modify "one-third" by an adverb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, writing-style, hyphenation, modifiers

Would it be correct to merge with hyphens *one-third-contiguously* in the following phrase?

> [I propose to elect by 3 quotas, each per one-thirds-contiguously of time-zones](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/709/i-propose-to-elect-by-3-quotas-each-per-one-thirds-contiguously-of-time-zones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. "One-third-contiguously" would indicate things that are only partially contiguous, which means that they would abut at something less substantial than a mathematical point (the minimum requirement for contiguity), and the whole phrase being used adverbially. Perhaps if you were to put it into context someone could suggest a wording less damaging to Broca's area.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify "one-third" with an adverb, put it in front with no hyphen:

> That's nearly one third of the total.
>
> I've eaten easily one third of the cake.
>
> We're roughly one third of the way there.
>
> Pay me exactly one third of the total.

However this tends to modify the amount, or how confident one is about the precision; I'm not sure exactly what you're saying but using "contiguously" in this position would sound strange and the meaning would be unclear.

You may better off using an adjective instead:

> each contiguous third

but inserting this back into your original sentence makes it clumsy; depending on your precise meaning something like

> per contiguous section making up one third of the time zones

may be your best bet.